# iOS playback RTMP with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, streaming, avfoundation, rtmp

I need to implement an iOS app that playback RTMP with AV. Exists any library for this propose? I have bean searched on Internet but I didn't found nothing or any example.

I think that I must capture frames and decodec because iOS don't playback rtmp.

I haven't got idea to where start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few providers i had come across few months back. 
You might want to refer them.

1. [cine.io](https://github.com/cine-io/cineio-broadcast-ios)
2. [VideoStream SDK for iOS](http://www.videostreamsdk.com/)
3. [Brightcove Player SDK for iOS](http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/mobile-sdks/brightcove-player-sdk-for-ios/index.html)
4. [RealTimeLibs](http://www.realtimelibs.com/)

All of above are paid ones.

There are also some open source libs:

1. [RTMP-Wrapper](https://github.com/ifactorylab/rtmp-wrapper)
2. [MediaLibDemos](https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: MediaLibDemos is private paying library (not open source)